# Method undefined when calling it from $ajax.success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When I call a method from the $ajax.success callback I get an undefined.

```
var someObj = {};
someObj.someMethod = function() {
    //code code
}

someObj.ajaxCall = function() {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax options
    })
        .done(function( data ) {
            this.someMethod();
    });
}
```

Comment: `this` is not what you think it is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use the call method of the function object:

```
someObj.ajaxCall = function() {
    $.ajax({
        //ajax options
    })
        .done(function( data ) {
            someMethod.call(someObj);
    });
}
```

Inside the success callback the this object is pointing the $ajax object which haven't a someMethod function defined.

Comment: It is not ideal to have `somemethod` being global if it only applies to a specific object type -- It defeatist object oriented programming if he cannot use the `someObj` for the functions

Comment: This seems like it either wouldn't work (if `someMethod` is a method of an object) or it's a bad idea to make it global.  This is NOT a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

As our good friend, Mr. SLaks has pointed out, you have a scope issue with regards to `this`

One solution other than the one posted could be saving a reference to the scope before the callback :

```
someObj.ajaxCall = function() {
    var _this = this;
    $.ajax({
        //ajax options
    })
        .done(function( data ) {
            _this.someMethod();
    });
}
```

Or, you can use the context option with `$.ajax()` to control the setting of the `this` value:

```
someObj.ajaxCall = function() {
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        // other ajax options
    })
        .done(function( data ) {
            this.someMethod();
    });
}
```

Comment: Much better solution that the currently accepted answer.  Can also use the `context` option with `$.ajax()` to make `this` be what you want it to be.